# Cordova 1.6 Iphone Email sending with attachment

Tags: iphone, cordova, email-attachments

Email attachments using phonegap in iPhone - I need to capture a picture and attach the captured image by default to mail composer and launch it. Can any one of you help in doing so. I used the `camera API` and I am successful in sending emails but not sure how to attach the image captured along with this email.

```
function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
    // Uncomment to view the base64 encoded image data
    // console.log(imageData);

    // Get image handle
    //
    var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

    // Unhide image elements
    //
    smallImage.style.display = 'block';

    // Show the captured photo
    // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
    //
    //smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;

    smallImage.src = imageData;
    alert("data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData);
    var args;

    cordova.exec(null, null, "EmailComposer", "showEmailComposer", [args]);
}
```

Even if it is not attachment and if it needs to be added to body of the email, then I used

```
 EmailComposer.prototype.showEmailComposer("Test","<html><body><img src=\""+imageData+"\" /></body></html>","test@example.com","","","YES");
```

Then I am able to see the image embedded inside the mail composer, while sending I did not get any errors and on receiving the email the image is not shown.